# How to remove a view from parent in appcelerator titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

Suppose we have something like this:

```
var parent = parentView; // A View
var child = Alloy.createController('ChildView',{});
parent.add(child);
```

And in the ChildView.js controller:

```
function closeView(){
    // remove ourself from parent how?
}
```

Can you do this somehow? From the closeView() remove the child view from its parent?

The way i can solve it i guess is sending in the parent view in the {} options to the childview and keep a reference there {parent:parentView}. And then do a parent.remove()... in my closeView(). But is there some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use events. All Alloy Controllers implement `BackBone.Events` so when you create the child attach a `close` event to it and have the parent remove the child.

The child should only be concerned with itself. knowing about how it interacts with its parent is leaking information and not following good SOLID design. Maintenance itself would be a nightmare not to mention the mental overhead to growk that kind of design.

#### Parent code:

```
var parent = parentView; // A View
var child = Alloy.createController('ChildView',{});
child.on('close', function () {
  parent.remove(child.getView());
});
parent.add(child.getView());
```

#### Child code:

```
function closeView(){
  $.trigger('close');
}
```

Comment: That worked fine.   Though i had to do  parent.add(child.getView()) and parent.remove(child.getView())

Comment: Really like this way much better than passing callbacks. However according to the article below its bad practice to create references to Alloy controllers. ie. "var child = Alloy.createController...". http://www.tidev.io/2014/09/18/cleaning-up-alloy-controllers/

Comment: Doing it all in one go seems to work though! For example: "parent.add(Alloy.createController('ChildView, {}).on('close', function(){ parent.remove(this.getView()); });

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass the reference to the parent to the child for this to work, as you mentioned

```
var child = Alloy.createController('ChildView',{parentView: parent});
```

Then in the childview:

```
function closeView(){
    $.args.parentView.remove($.getView());
}
```

You can also do it the other way around by letting the parent take care of it:

in childview:

```
$.trigger('removeMe');
```

In the parent controller:

```
child.on('removeMe',function(){
    parent.remove(child);
}
```

Comment: No this is not a good idea! this muddles the seperation of concerns and is *not* SOLID. Even the docs describe this kind of thing using events!